# How long should I leave after spraying a glyphosate weed killer before I cut back the weeds?

Tags: weed-control

I have applied a glyphosate weed killer and I can see that over the course of a few days the leaves will wither and after a couple of weeks most are completely dry and shrivelled.  When I am clearning some areas I would like to get on with cutting back the surface growth and digging out some of the root as soon as practical.  How long should I wait after applying a glyphosate weed killer before I cut back?

In my limited understanding the chemicals are absorbed though the leaves and make their way through the plant to kill or at least weaken the roots.  My assumption is that his may take some time to happen.

I understand that different plants and conditions will require different times.  That being the case I am happy to go by indicators for when is a good time such as; the leaves start to shrivel, brown patches on the leaves have appeared, the plant has completely died back and decomposed via natural processes (although I hope to not need to wait that long).

Bonus points for suggestions of when to reapply too.  I usually go by when most stuff has started dying but some things have not they get another dose.

The specific product I am applying at the moment is Weedol Rootkill Plus which seems to be doing a good job if applied librally to the leaves during a warm still day as the instructions suggest.

Comment: You should note that not all plants are killed by glyphosate. Mature violets, for example, will wither but will return from the base. Plants with very finely cut leaves like Queen Anne's Lace, or with hairy leaves like common mullein, will also wither but will not die (my own thought is that the cut-leaves don't pick up enough of the chemical and the fuzziness doesn't allow much of the chemical to actually reach the leaf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the user guide:

> REPLANTING AND SOWING: Where a light covering of annual weeds has been
>   treated – area can be  re-planted 1 day after spraying. Where a dense
>   covering of annual and / or perennial weeds has been treated – area
>   can be re-planted 7 days after spraying (to allow the weed killer to
>   move to the roots before cultivation).

If you stick with seven days you should be fine. I've been using Roundup Pro for many years and seven days has always worked fine for me.